# Typescript: Derive Interface from Function Definition

Tags: typescript

I'd love to do something like this:

```
function myFunction(arg1: string, arg2: number): boolean {
    //some code here
}

interface myInterface {
    someOtherProperty: string
    myFunction: myFunction // should be the equivalent of (arg1: string, arg2: Number) => boolean
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typeof` in a type context to get the type of any value:

```
function myFunction(arg1: string, arg2: number): boolean {
  return false;
}

interface myInterface {
    someOtherProperty: string
    myFunction: typeof myFunction 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQFsCeAxa9lQAUAhgE4DmAjAFyoDOcpCU5ANKmeQEy1QToAjAKakAlLQFIkAGyHE0Ab1CpUpIXAik0YYtLpCA3KAC+oUMzgidMIRkwBJKJdLXbSkCpV0k6IQHk4AAsRAAVSJAAHEThMWgYmFmVPLFxYRBRaGKikMDtU-BRUEyA)

Comment: When you use it in a type context, that is. :-)